# Reload installed Firefox WebExtensions' background script for debugging?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I know:

- For a content script, I just need to reload the web page, and the content scripts will be reloaded
- For add-ons loaded as a [temporary add-on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Temporary_Installation_in_Firefox), there is a <kbd>Reload</kbd> button in `about:debugging`: a click on the button will cause the background scripts to be reloaded.

But, I want to reload **background scripts** for an **installed** Firefox WebExtensions to debug it. The <kbd>Reload</kbd> button for installed add-ons is disabled. I'm using Firefox v51.

I want to do this, because the part of script that I want to debug, is loaded at the startup of extension loading.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to go to `about:addons` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> on OSX). On the "Extensions" tab (tabs are along the left) there will be a line for your extension. On that line will be a <kbd>Disable</kbd> button and a <kbd>Remove</kbd> button.  If you click the <kbd>Disable</kbd> button, your add-on will be disabled.  That button will then change to <kbd>Enable</kbd>. You can then click the <kbd>Enable</kbd> button to re-enable your add-on.

Performing that process will unload and reload your background scripts.

Comment: When I disable the add-on, the Developer Tool for background scripts becomes blank, and my breakpoints are lost. I want to reload the background scripts to trigger my breakpoints. Is it possible?

Comment: If the break points are ones which you have set after the scripts are loaded, i.e. not [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statements, then, no. I suspect that even with using `debugger` it might be tricky. You may need to resort to `console.log()` debugging.